# MVC3 model binding does not update the partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Any ideas why after adding Model Binding to the controller, the partial view no longer gets updated:

All I did was change the signature:

from:

```
public ActionResult About2()
```

to:

```
public ActionResult About2([Bind(Prefix = "SomePropertyToBind")] String modelString)
```

and here is the Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("About2", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "property22", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{    
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelTest.SomePropertyToBind, new SelectList(Model.ModelTest.list, "property1", "property2"))

    <button type="submit" id="test">Click me</button>    
}
```

I've attached a sample: http://www.sendspace.com/file/7boodv

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your project and the problem is in the following code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult About2([Bind(Prefix = "SomePropertyToBind")] String modelString)
        {
```

using this attribute `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` is the problem, you cannot open your desired page without having a `GET` action to serve your request.

of course removing this attribute worked perfectly, but if you need to reserve it, add another action with the same name to serve the `GET` request to your page like this:

```
public ActionResult About2()
        {

   // Initialization code for About2 page

}
```

That's it. feel free to ask if it's still not working, thanks.

Comment: @user683302 - No need to remove the `HttpPost` attribute (`[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` can be substituted simply by `[HttpPost]` in MVC 3), just add the option `HttpMethod = "POST"` to the `AjaxOptions` object in the Asjax form.

Comment: I tried both POST and GET and the view still doesn't get updated. The binding works, I get the correct value inside the About2() method, however, when I click on the button the dropdown value never changes (inspecting the DOM reveals that the updates never make it there). If I remove the biding everything works as expected so I'm at a loss here as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you describe what exactly you need to achieve here?
 I've a copy of your project and can simulate it here, just tell e what you need.

Comment: I just want to be able to figure out why is it that the partial view does not get updated when I click the "Click me" button. If I remove [Bind(Prefix = "SomePropertyToBind")] String modelString from the signature of the About2() method it works. For instance, clicking the button should generate a new color once in a while which it does, but the selection never changes on the front end.